# array push and sort ASC order based on array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

**activeTopics**

```
$activeTopics = Array
            (
                "100" => Array
                    (
                        "activationDate" => "2018-11-28 16:19:22"
                    ),

                "200" => Array
                    (
                        "activationDate" => "2018-11-28 16:21:06"
                    ),

                "300" => Array
                    (
                        "activationDate" => "2018-11-28 16:23:18"
                    )

            );
```

**pedagogyTopics**

```
 $pedagogyTopics = Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "pedagogyID" => 200,
            "higherLevelStatus" => "available"
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "pedagogyID" => 100,
            "higherLevelStatus" => "No"
        )

);
```

My requirement is, `pedagogyTopics` pedagogyID is equal to `activeTopics` index means i want to take `activationDate` and push to pedagogyTopics,

After that I want to sort the array based on `activation date` ASC order, I have written code it is working fine also. my question is whether I did correctly or not? or we can simplify the code?  I have huge records in DB. i am using two foreach loops here, that's why I am worrying

[click here for demo](https://eval.in/1063879)

Comment: I think its correct. but I would alpha numeric index in $activeTopics

Comment: I think you can put `$sort['activationDate'][$k] = $v['activationDate'];` in the same loop where you push the `activationDate`.

Comment: @ resting , can you please update my code